# ResearchKit optional and conditional step (survey task)

Tags: ios, swift, researchkit

How can I specify a step where user will be redirect to when he clicks on ‘skip‘ button in a step with predicate navigation rules ?

For now it redirects to the start of the task.

Here is the optional step :

```
// multiple choices question
let multipleQuestionsStepTitle = "what is your gender ?"
let textChoices = [ORKTextChoice(text: "Female", value: 0),
                   ORKTextChoice(text: "Male", value: 1),
                   ORKTextChoice(text: "idk", value: 2)]
let multipleQuestionsAnswerFormat: ORKTextChoiceAnswerFormat = ORKAnswerFormat.choiceAnswerFormatWithStyle(.SingleChoice, textChoices: textChoices)
let multipleQuestionsStep = ORKQuestionStep(identifier: "TextChoiceQuestionStep", title: multipleQuestionsStepTitle, answer: multipleQuestionsAnswerFormat)
multipleQuestionsStep.optional = true

steps += [multipleQuestionsStep]
```

And here is the navigation rule:

```
let task = ORKNavigableOrderedTask(identifier: "SurveyTask", steps: steps)

var predicateRule: ORKPredicateStepNavigationRule
let predicateFemale: NSPredicate = ORKResultPredicate.predicateForChoiceQuestionResultWithResultSelector(ORKResultSelector(resultIdentifier: "TextChoiceQuestionStep"), expectedAnswerValue: 0)
// invert of previous predicate
let predicateNotFemale: NSPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate.init(notPredicateWithSubpredicate: predicateFemale)
predicateRule = ORKPredicateStepNavigationRule.init(resultPredicates: [predicateNotFemale], destinationStepIdentifiers: ["IntroStep"], defaultStepIdentifier: "ImageChoiceQuestionStep", validateArrays: false)

task.setNavigationRule(predicateRule, forTriggerStepIdentifier: "TextChoiceQuestionStep")
```

I would assume that if we skip the step, we would be redirect to the `defaultStepIdentifier`, but it's not the case here.

I didn't find anything in documentation about setting optional to false if we have navigation rules, so maybe someone has a solution on how to do that?

Comment: @rsanchezsaez Any suggestion for this one?

Comment: can you open an issue on Github site